# Decode ASCII characters inside a String

Tags: java, url, ascii

I am looking for a Java instruction to convert

```
http://dbpedia.org/resource/NVA_%28film%29
```

to

```
http://dbpedia.org/resource/NVA_(film)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
URLEncoder.encode("http://www.your-url.com, "UTF-8");
```

and this to reverse

```
URLDecoder.decode(encodedString, "UTF-8");
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware, offhand, of easy way to do this with just the JDK classes, but Apache Commons Codec has a useful [`URLCodec`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/net/URLCodec.html) utility:

```
String url = "http://dbpedia.org/resource/NVA_%28film%29";
URLCodec codec = new URLCodec();
String decodedURL = codec.decode(url);
```